# Convert UNIX epoch to Date object

Tags: r, time, r-faq

I'm plotting and performing calculations on uniformly distributed time series. The timestamps are currently stored as integers representing the number of seconds since the UNIX epoch (e.g. `1352068320`), but `Date` objects seem more appropriate for plotting. How can I do the conversion?

I've read `?Date`, `?as.Date` and `??epoch`, but seem to have missed that information.

Answer (score 261, accepted):

Go via `POSIXct` and you want to set a `TZ` there -- here you see my (Chicago) default:

```
R> val <- 1352068320
R> as.POSIXct(val, origin="1970-01-01")
[1] "2012-11-04 22:32:00 CST"
R> as.Date(as.POSIXct(val, origin="1970-01-01"))
[1] "2012-11-05" 
R>
```

*Edit:* A few years later, we can now use the [anytime](https://cran.r-project.org/package=anytime) package:

```
R> library(anytime)
R> anytime(1352068320)
[1] "2012-11-04 16:32:00 CST"
R> anydate(1352068320)
[1] "2012-11-04"
R>
```

Note how all this works without *any format or origin arguments*.

Comment: I have timestamps like `1415560016876`. http://www.epochconverter.com/ converts this to a date with no problem. Your code above gives me stuff like `"46832-11-09 12:47:33 EDT"`...

Comment: Try dividing that by 1000: `as.POSIXct(1415560016876/1000, origin="1970-01-01")` gets  "2014-11-09 13:06:56.875 CST" and you need to ensure whether _seconds_ are expected (as for R) or _milliseconds_.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel: Thanks! Is there a guide about when to divide by 1000 and when not to?? Just trying to understand the basics.

Comment: @Shambho: Just do the reverse and see if you're in the same order of magnitude: `print(as.numeric(Sys.time()))`

Comment: I have the same case, but I need the millisecond data, so I can't divide by 1000. Any ideas on how to represent these as dates?

Comment: It's always the same: scale what you have to that it arrives at the same _scale_ as the current time:  `print(as.numeric(Sys.time()), digits=16)` with the six digits is what my Linux system.  Also, you *can* divide by 1000; this does not truncate.

Comment: How would you extract just the local time from the     R variable, and dump the date?

Comment: Look at the available print formats, eg via `help(strptime)`.

Answer (score 34):

With `library(lubridate)`, numeric representations of date and time saved as the number of seconds since
1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC, can be coerced into dates with `as_datetime()`:

```
lubridate::as_datetime(1352068320)

[1] "2012-11-04 22:32:00 UTC"
```

Comment: Strictly speaking this is not correct as it isn't _lubridate_ which has the "numeric represenation [...] as number of seconds" but _base R_ just as my four-years older answer already showed -- so what we have here is a _lubridate_ alternative to the two commands I already showed earlier.

Comment: Dear @DirkEddelbuettel,
Thank you for feedback.
Yes, this is -lubridate- alternative. 
My answer could be re-edited as:


Numeric representations of date and time saved as the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC, can be coerced into dates with lubridate::as_datetime()

Comment: Sure. As they can with `as.POSIXct` (needing an origin) or `anytime`.

Comment: I see.
Corrected