# convert date to unix time in R

Tags: r

I want to convert "2013-09-16" into unix time.

I found [Convert UNIX epoch to Date object in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13456241/convert-unix-epoch-to-date-object-in-r) but I need to do the reverse of that.

Thanks!

Comment: What did you try and why didn't it work?

Comment: format.POSIXct("2013-09-16", '%F')

Comment: You don't have an object of `POSIXct` there, you have a `character` type object. You want `as.POSIXct()`.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Quite simple:

`as.numeric(as.POSIXct("2013-09-16 2:13:46 EST"))`

Comment: Does this approach consider summer-/winter time?

Comment: @rmuc8 `EST` is standard time. If it was daylight time then it would be `EDT`

Answer (score 14):

Simply cast to numeric:

```
as.numeric(as.POSIXct("2013-09-06", format="%Y-%m-%d"))
# [1] 1378418400
```

Answer (score 0):

This tipe of time is useful for YahooFinance i'll leave you a code
if you want to see 60 days before until today:

```
  window <- 60
  tempo<-as.character(Sys.time())
  substr(time, 12, 24) <- "00:00:00"
  tempo<-as.POSIXct(tempo)
  end_date <- ceiling(as.numeric(as.POSIXct(tempo)))
  start_date <- ceiling(as.numeric(as.POSIXct(tempo - window*86400)))
```

This code will give you an interval for download the time that you want.

WAC.