# Unable to convert Epoch time to Date using R

Tags: r, epoch

I am trying to convert epoch time to date. I have a numeric array with epoch times.

I tried this -

```
print(as.POSIXct(x), origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "CST6CDT"))
```

Where `x` represents the numeric array with epoch times

```
#Output:
" CDT" " CST" " CDT" " CDT" " CDT" " CST" " CDT" " CST"
```

I have tried these-

```
print(as.POSIXct(1403878908842, origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "CST6CDT"))
print(as.POSIXct(1403878908842, origin = "1970-01-01", tz = ""))
```

But they all return timezones not the converted date.

Comment: this is nearly verbatim http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13456241/convert-unix-epoch-to-date-object-in-r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
as.POSIXct(1403878908842/1000, origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "")
## [1] "2014-06-27 10:21:48 EDT"

as.POSIXct(1403878908842/1000, origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "CST6CDT")
## [1] "2014-06-27 09:21:48 CDT"
```