# R: Convert large column of epoch times to date object

Tags: r, data.table, epoch, posixct

Similar to the problem in [Convert UNIX epoch to Date object in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13456241/convert-unix-epoch-to-date-object-in-r), mine deals with one column of a large data table (about 250k rows). The column is a vector of many epoch times, e.g., `dt$time=`

```
c(1388839764L, 1388846894L, 1388998785L, 1389496318L, 1389525690L,
1389545726L, 1389608509L, 1389672286L, 1389696208L, 1389747353L)
```

How to convert such a long vector to date object? `as.POSIXct(dt$time, origin='1970-01-01')` has poor efficiency for such vector. While `fastPOSIXct` from `fasttime` doesn't have the `origin` as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `fasttime` library and convert this vector of `longs` via a matrix calculation to the right origin.

Comment: I assume you want to set a different origin. To get there, you can just do some simple calculation with the vector before feeding theses values to the `fasttime` library. What should be the first date in your vector, `'2014-01-04T13:49:24'`?

Comment: Nope, sorry I didn't make it clear. It is because `fastPOSIXct(dt$time)` gives me `NA`; `as.POSIXct(1388839764, origin='1970-01-01')="2014-01-04 20:49:24 CST"`

Comment: Okay, I'll come back to this but I'm busy now. Sorry!